# List of divergent series and their summations

Tags: big-list, divergent-series

On the web one can manage to find a lot of lists of convergent series and their summation btw I didn't find (at least on a quick search) a corrispective list of divergent series, does anyone know one ? Maybe a list with their summation obtained with some methods (Euler, Cesaro, Abel, Ramanujan, and so on...)

Comment: You may have better luck searching for "summabilty method"...

Comment: what about wikipedia? There is already a certain list. Why not extend that list?